# Caesar cipher revision

Tags: java, inheritance, encryption, caesar-cipher

I posted this similar thread yesterday thinking that I've finished it but when I run test cases 4/20 fail from the `decrypt1()` method of the `Caesar class`. In the `Caesar class`, I'm trying to figure out what's wrong with my `decrypt1()` method's code when if I run the following test case (which fails):

```
@Test (timeout=2000)
public void test_Caesar_15(){
    assertEquals('Q',new CaesarCipher(100) .decrypt1('X'));
}
```

the answer should be `81` when what I get is only `101`. Another case is this:

```
@Test (timeout=2000)
public void test_Caesar_21(){
    assertEquals("catfood",new CaesarCipher(17, lowerSpace).decrypt("trjweeu"));
}
```

when the output should be `catfood` but I'm getting smth like this `ca fvvd`. Could smb please help me with the decrypt1() method/guide me towards the fixing the code? Assume that the Alphabet object includes every character shown in the `Alphabet class` as the `DEFAULT`. I've included here three interconnecter classes so it could be easier to track the bug in `decrypt1()` method.

```
public class CaesarCipher extends SymmetricCipher {

    protected int shift;

    public CaesarCipher(int shift, Alphabet alphabet)
    {
        super(alphabet);
        this.shift = shift;

    }

    public CaesarCipher(int shift)
    {

        super(Alphabet.DEFAULT);
        this.shift = shift;
    }

    public String encrypt(String s)
    {
        String encrypted = super.encrypt(s);
        return encrypted;


    }

    public char encrypt1(char c) throws NotInAlphabetException
    {

        int index = 0;
        int rotateIndex = 0;
        char shiftedChar = 0;

        index = alphabet.indexOf(c);
        if((index + shift) > alphabet.length())
        {
            rotateIndex = rotate(index, shift);
            shiftedChar = alphabet.get(rotateIndex);
        }
        else if((index + shift) < 0)
        {
            rotateIndex = rotate(index, shift);
            shiftedChar = alphabet.get(rotateIndex);
        }
        else
        {
            index += shift;
            shiftedChar = alphabet.get(index);
        }

        return shiftedChar;


    }

    public String decrypt(String s)
    {
        String decrypted = super.decrypt(s);
        return decrypted;
    }
    public char decrypt1(char c)
    {
        int index = 0;
        int rotateIndex = 0;
        char shiftedChar = 0;

        index = alphabet.indexOf(c);

        if((index - shift) > alphabet.length())
        {
            rotateIndex = rotate(index, shift);
            shiftedChar = alphabet.get(rotateIndex);
        }
        else if((index - shift) < 0)
        {

            rotateIndex = rotate(index, shift);
            shiftedChar = alphabet.get(rotateIndex);
        }
        else
        {
            index = index - shift;
            shiftedChar = alphabet.get(index);
        }

        return shiftedChar;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return "Caesar Cipher (shift="+shift+")";
    }

}


public abstract class SymmetricCipher extends Cipher {

    protected Alphabet alphabet;

    public SymmetricCipher (Alphabet alphabet)
    {
        this.alphabet = alphabet;
    }

    public int wrapInt(int i)
    {
        int index = 0;
        if (i >= alphabet.length())
            index = Math.abs(i) % alphabet.length();
        else if (i < 0)
        {
            int temp = Math.abs(i) % alphabet.length();
            index = alphabet.length() - temp;
        }
        else 
            index = i;

        return index;
    }

    public int rotate(int index, int shift)
    {
        int result = 0;

        if (shift > 0)
        {
            result = (index + shift) % alphabet.length();
        }

        else if (shift < 0)
        {
            if(index < Math.abs(shift))
            {
                int temp = Math.abs(index + shift);
                result = alphabet.length() - temp;

            }
            else 
                result = index + shift ;
        }   


        return result;
    }

    public Alphabet getAlphabet()
    {
        return this.alphabet;
    }

    public String encrypt(String s) 
    {
        String string = "";
        char c = 0;
        char encrypted = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
        {
            c = s.charAt(i);
            encrypted = encrypt1(c);
            string += encrypted;
        }
        return string;


    }

    public String decrypt(String s) throws NotInAlphabetException
    {
        String string = "";
        char c = 0;
        char decrypted = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
        {
            c = s.charAt(i);
            decrypted = decrypt1(c);
            string += decrypted;
        }
        return string;


    }

    protected abstract char encrypt1(char c);

    protected abstract char decrypt1(char c);


}

public class Alphabet {


    private String symbols;
    public static final Alphabet DEFAULT = new Alphabet("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz 1234567890!@#$%^&*()_+-=[]{}\\|;:'\",./?<>");

    public Alphabet(String symbols)
    {
        this.symbols = symbols;
    }

    public int indexOf(char c) 
    {
        Alphabet temp = new Alphabet(symbols);
        for(int i = 0; i < symbols.length(); i++)
        {
            if(c == symbols.charAt(i))
                return symbols.indexOf(c) ;
        }

        throw new NotInAlphabetException (c, temp); 
    }

    public char get(int i) 
    {
        Alphabet temp = new Alphabet(symbols);
        char c = 0;
        if (i > this.symbols.length())
            throw new NotInAlphabetException (c, temp);
        else 
            return symbols.charAt(i);
    }

    public int length()
    {
        return symbols.length();
    }

    public String getSymbols()
    {
        return symbols;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return "Alphabet("+this.symbols+")";
    }

    public boolean equals(Object other)
    {
        if(other instanceof Alphabet)
        {
            Alphabet temp = (Alphabet) other;
            return this.symbols.equals(temp.symbols);

        }
        else 
            return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I refactored a bit of your code to separate concerns a bit. For instance, the decrypt1() and encrypt1() methods have switching on the difference/sum of index -/+ shift. But this code logically belongs in rotate(). With that in mind the decrypt1() and encrypt1() become the clear functions:

```
@Override
public char encrypt1(char c) throws NotInAlphabetException {

    int index = alphabet.indexOf(c);
    int rotateIndex = rotate(index, shift);
    char shiftedChar = alphabet.get(rotateIndex);

    return shiftedChar;

}

@Override
public char decrypt1(char c) {

    int index = alphabet.indexOf(c);
    int rotateIndex = rotate(index, -shift);
    char shiftedChar = alphabet.get(rotateIndex);

    return shiftedChar;
}
```

This is clearly the code of the Caesar cipher: encryption shifts the character from indexC = indexP + shift and decryption takes it back indexP = indexC - shift. This moves all of the weight of shifting into rotate.

It is of the utmost importance that rotate now supports negative shifts. Note that a shift by the size of the alphabet is the same as no shift at all, so we can keep adding the alphabet size to the shift until the shift is positive. You already considered the additional special case where shift brings the index outside of the alphabet. The following rotate solves both issues:

```
public int rotate(int index, int shift) {

    while (shift < 0) {
        shift += alphabet.length();
    }

    return (index + shift) % alphabet.length();
}
```

Assuming that lower space is

```
Alphabet lowerSpace = new Alphabet("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ");
```

the above functions solve the problems you have shown. I should point out that you don't need to override encrypt() and decrypt() in CaesarCipher since you are just unnecessarily adding an explicit layer of dynamic dispatch back to the super class.

Comment: so this means I shuld change my whole rotate method to the that you've mentioned?